# How can i take input from keyboard with ruby?

Tags: ruby, input

How can I take input from keyboard with Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
puts "In which city do you stay?"  
STDOUT.flush  
city = gets.chomp  
puts "The city is " + city
```